# How to disable default animation of a button

Tags: flutter

I'm new to learning flutter and have made an app that has two outlined buttons that get enabled or disabled on certain conditions. When the button is enabled or when it is disabled there is a short delay. Here's the problem:

[image]

How do I remove the delay? I want the button to be enabled or disabled instantly. Any ideas?

I am running the app on simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass different key to the outlined button in case button is disabled/enabled.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData.dark(
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int number = 0;

  void _onRemovePressed() {
    setState(() {
      number--;
    });
  }

  void _onAddPressed() {
    setState(() {
      number++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: const Text('Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              number.toString(),
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                OutlinedButton(
                  key: number <= 0 ? null : const ValueKey('RemoveButton'),
                  onPressed: number <= 0 ? null : _onRemovePressed,
                  child: const Text('Remove'),
                ),
                OutlinedButton(
                  onPressed: _onAddPressed,
                  child: const Text('Add'),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This works but why do we have to set the key for the button delay animation to stop?

Comment: Having different keys between builds make the older widget dispose and new one being created. So with different key, it is new widget and older one having some remaining animation is disposed. But to the user, it seems like it is same button.